# Ubuntu server 18.04 usb automount like it does desktop

Tags: server, 18.04, automount

How to auto-mount usb drive in `/media/{USERNAME}/{VOLUMEID}` in Ubuntu server 18.04. It work on my desktop but doesn't on server.

I tried `usbmount`, but it works differently.

Comment: OK. After a while a found a reasonable solution. By default usbmount make a link into /var/run/usbmount on disk insertion and delete it on remove disk. This link have a VOLUMEID name. This is not exact as on my desktop computer. And still don't know how it realized on it.

Comment: Is there a feature like but for harddrives?

Answer (score 1):

You can either manually mount your usb drive:

```
fdisk -l
```

Recognize you device, eg: /dev/sdb1 is your USB partition

```
mkdir -p /mnt/usb
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
```

Or, add a udev rule which will automount all the devices of type USB in a specified directory.